# Фоновое чтение ini файла настроек

Tags: python

В питоне новичок.

Никак не могу осилить как сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения фоном запускалось чтение конфигурации и обновление централизованной переменной с конфигурациями доступной для всех. 
Есть проект:

- main:

  - **init**.py
  - main.py
  - psql.py
  - logconfig.py
  - bot.py
  - config.cfg

В `config.cfg` лежат настройки для разных частей приложения. Т.е. если мы вносим какое-то изменение(например пароль для базы или токен для бота), чтобы не перезапускать всё приложение, мы меняем настройки  в `config.cfg` и он перечитывает и хранит их у себя.

Можно в каждом файле прописать отделный тред(например), который будет перечитывать свою секцию:

```
class Config:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    def _config_read(self):
        while True:
            self.config.read('telenotify.cfg')
            print(self.config['DEFAULT'])
            time.sleep(1)
    def config_read(self):
        Thread(target=self._config_read).start()
```

Но тогда придётся в каждом файле запускать отдельный поток, который будет вычитвать свою секцию.
Но можно ли сделать так, что бы был централизованный доступ до конфигурации в этом случае? Т.е. как сделать этот класс таким, что его не надо было инициализировать. Чтобы он стартовал при запуске приложения и можно было обратиться к `config`

Answer (score -1):

Используйте Модуль json. сохранение в файл словарей dict. Как вариант